# Open Office Installation Help

Tags: openoffice, redhat-enterprise-linux

I've been racking my brain (and the internet) for way too long on this issue, and I could really use some help. I've tried just about everything I can think of to get this issue resolved, and I've run out of ideas on what to do.

I am trying to install Open Office 3.2.0 on a Red Hat server that doesn't have a GUI, but I'm having relentless dependency issues. My currently installation (I've tried with 3.2.1 first, but the only headless RPM I could find was for 3.2.0)

The files that I am using for my installation are the following: 
- OOo_3.2.0_Linux_x86-64_install-rpm-wJRE_en-US.tar.gz (182MB) from OpenOffice.org's download site: files/stable/3.2.0/ 
- openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64.rpm from http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=openoffice.org-headless

From here, I unzip the tar to get the folder: OOO320_m12_native_packed-1_en-US.9483/RPMS. If I try "rpm -i *.rpm" at this point, I get dependency issues because of the *gnome-integration* and *kde-integration* files, so I mv them to another folder.

When I run the rpm -i command again, everything runs as expected.

Now I move to the location of the headless rpm I mentioned above, and attempt to get that file. When that runs, I get the following output:

`warning: desktop-integration/openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID e8e40fde 
error: Failed dependencies:`

```
    libbasegfxlx.so()(64bit) is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    libi18npaperlx.so()(64bit) is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)(64bit) is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit) is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    libtllx.so()(64bit) is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    libuno_sal.so.3()(64bit) is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    libuno_sal.so.3(UDK_3.1)(64bit) is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    libuno_sal.so.3(UDK_3_0_0)(64bit) is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    libvcllx.so()(64bit) is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    libvos3gcc3.so()(64bit) is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    openoffice.org-core = 1:3.2.0-12.33.fc13 is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    openoffice.org-ure = 1:3.2.0-12.33.fc13 is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64 
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by openoffice.org-headless-3.2.0-12.33.fc13.x86_64
```

Unfortunately, using YUM is out of the question, as openoffice is not being listed in its repository.

Personally, I'm very green at using Redhat, though I do have a couple months of using Linux under my belt.

Comment: this is just dependency troubleshooting...install the appropriate libraries and openoffice will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you found was built for a much newer system, and cannot even be unpacked properly with the currently installed `rpm` — the `rpmlib(PayloadIsXz)` and `rpmlib(FileDigests)` dependency errors are due to the version of `rpm` which does not support the newer package format. Apparently the switch to xz compression was done in Fedora 12, so you don't have any chance to install Fedora packages newer than `*.fc11` on this system.

Comment: Interesting... Let me take a look into an older version of Open Office.  I checked the version of RedHat and found that this machine is using RHEL 5.5, which seems to be equivalent to Fedora 6 (please correct me if I'm wrong), so this seems like it might be the answer.  I'll let you know how that works out.

Comment: We ended up going a different direction with a simple pdf printer.  Thanks for the input to the both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd use `yum` to install the packages, even if you're not installing them from a repository. You just need to make sure that there's a "/" in there somewhere, e.g. `yum install ./*.rpm`.

However, you have a bigger problem. `rpmlib(*)` dependencies are, for the most part, unfulfillable on a given system unless they're already in place, since they represent base rpmlib functionality. You will need to grab the appropriate SRPM from Fedora and rebuild, probably using [mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock).

Answer (score 0):

Fedora (and presumably RHEL) ships LibreOffice (currently version 6.3.4.2 for Fedora 31), not OpenOffice (left it behind shortly after the split happened back in 2000). Have you tried to install that one from the official repositories? Have you looked at not-so-official ones, like [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)?

Or grab the package from the [source](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download).